# Is a Transactional Replication Snapshot processed as a 'bulk insert'

Tags: sql-server-2012, snapshot, merge-replication, transactional-replication

I have a Merge replication that sources on a subscription from a Transactional Replication. I know that the triggers regarding the Merge replication are not fired by 'bulk inserts':

> Microsoft: When data is loaded into tables using the bcp Utility or the BULK
>   INSERT command, by default, the merge replication triggers that
>   maintain tracking data in the MSmerge_contents system table are not
>   fired.

For establishing the transactional replication a snapshot is needed. Question: is the snapshot a bulk insert; will it not fire the merge triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot can only be done when the merge publication is dropped. Otherwise I get an error saying that the tables are locked by replication.

Bottom line is  that it is not possible to do a snapshot on a replication where the subscription database is a source for an other replication.

Besides this, according to Microsoft: "The snapshot is generated as a set of bulk copy program (BCP) files."

So to my knowledge the snapshot is processed as a bulk insert.

Please correct me if I am wrong!